# Is it possible to set parameters like inertial, collisions in launch not in urdf?

Tags: urdf, roslaunch, collision, ros-kinetic, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm working on a robot. I didn't set parameters inertial and collisions in my URDF. Is it possible to set these params in launch file? How? I know that I can change the URDF file, but it is nessesary?
I need the launch to spawn the URDF model and Gazebo world.

Thanks for all answers. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287649/is-it-possible-to-set-parameters-like-inertial,-collisions-in-launch-not-in-urdf?/) by [dorothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/34239/dorothea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to set these params in launch file?

No, not directly.

You could however probably use the [YAML support](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#YAML_support) in `xacro` to generate a urdf with values taken from a YAML file and use that.

---

Edit:

> No, not directly.

I have to nuance this a bit: it is possible to pass arguments to `xacro` when it converts your xacro to a urdf. However, afaik you cannot give it entire blocks, so I'm not sure that would scale very well for the things that you want to parameterise. I feel I would still recommend looking into the YAML support.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0